# Adapter leads code to http://localhost:8088/users but the Tomcat server says ( http://localhost:8088/users ) not available

Tags: servlets, ember.js, model, adapter

I have some doubts that I am having application adapter, serializer, model, for storing/retrieving the user details.

using Emberjs Java servlet with org.json ajax ember-data/store adapter serializer...

Any perfect example to understand will be expected..

UserModel
@attr username
@attr mobilenumber

Adapter
host: http://localhost:8088 and
namespace: ' '

Here when I use this server says http://localhost:8088/users not available. But the servlet code is available inside http://localhost:8088/users/saveuserservlet and http://localhost:8088/users/getuserservlet.

Is it necessary to have json file in api, when we have servlet for processing data.

Provide any suggestions.

How do I represent host: and  namespace: so that it leads to the java servlet code.
How do I get data from response using get method ie for select * from users;

any suggestion for 200 parser error

Aslo in UserViewRoute...

return this.store.findAll('user'); --> Promise rejected with unexpected token